# CoCreateInstance fails with error "System can not find the file specified"

Tags: c++, com

I have .NET COM dll which I am trying to load from unmanaged C++ code. I am trying to do `CoCreateInstance` from my code which fails with the error "System can not find the file specified". (HRESULT value is `0x80070002`). Just to see whether there are any problems with the registration of the component , I tried the same piece of code from my tester. There I am able to create the instance correctly. Also, strangely in the debug mode of my main application `CoCreateInstance` succeeds but fails only in release mode. Does anybody has any idea what could be wrong or how can I find the root cause of the problem? I already opened the COM dll in dependency walker and it didn't show any errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How exactly did you register the .NET assembly?

Comment: @sharptooth: Something like: `RegAsm.exe" "C:\A.Core.dll" /codebase`. It gives the warning "RegAsm : warning RA0000 : Registering an unsigned assembly with /codebase can cause your assembly to interfere with other applications that may be installed on the same computer. The /codebase switch is intended to be used only with signed assemblies. Please give your assembly a strong name and re-register it." I tried without /codebase switch also.

Comment: Using `/codebase` is the right thing to do. Your best bet is to start Process Monitor and see what file exactly is not found and why.

Comment: Tried with process monitor too. Still it doesn't clearly say which file is missing. It fails to read some registry and other things but not able to pinpoint what exactly is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COM doesn't normally generate an ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.  But the CLR certainly does, common when trying to find a dependent assembly for example.  Be sure to run regasm /codebase from the Release build directory.  And use Fuslogvw.exe to trace assembly resolution problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I am a newbie to .NET and didn't know about the Fuslogvw.exe tool. It really helped. The issue was due to the wrong .NET version specified in my app.config file.